# Making Bitcoin Core 0.12.0 maximize by bandwidth

Tags: bitcoin-core, bandwidth

[Bitcoin Core 0.12.0](https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.12.0) added many bandwidth (e.g., `maxuploadtarget`) and rate limiting (e.g., with `maxmempool`) features.

I have `maxuploadtarget` set to 0 (default; unlimited), yet I used to get several gigabytes of traffic each day. Now I only get a few hundred. Why?

What must I do to make Bitcoin core maximize my bandwidth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new option is called `maxuploadtarget`. It joins `maxconnections` and `listen` in the list of things that can be used to control the bandwidth and resource usage of your Bitcoin client. `maxuploadtarget` controls the bandwidth used in a much more precise way than was previously possible without external tools.

`maxuploadtarget` is off by default. You don't need to do anything. More documentation is available [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/reduce-traffic.md).

Comment: Yes, but I used to have several gigabytes of traffic per day. Now I only get a few hundred, even with `maxuploadtarget=0` (unlimited). Why?

Comment: Several gigabytes per day sounds like someone was downloading the blockchain from you. Perhaps they're done?